# Salesforce before update Trigger Validation

Tags: trigger, account

Hi I am trying to validate a few fields in salesforce when a trigger is fired in the accounts.

**My Code**

```
trigger AccountCallout on Account (before update) {
// make the asynchronous web service callout   
for (Account a : Trigger.new) {     
    if(a.Name != null && a.Email__c !=null )
    {
      //Some Operations
    }
    else
    {
  a.Email__c.adderror('There was a problem updating the accounts. Email cannot be null');
    }
  }
}
```

**Error**
message is not being displayed on the page and the fields are getting updated

Comment: Are you just mixing `and`/`or`? And there is no readily apparent reason to avoid `Validation Rule` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this,

```
trigger accountTrigger1 on Account (Before Update) {

    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {     
    if(a.Number_of_Contacts__c != null  )
    {
      //Some Operations
    }
    else
    {
        a.Number_of_Contacts__c.adderror('There was a problem updating the accounts. Email cannot be null');
    }
  }

}
```

This worked for custom field.[image: check this]

Comment: is there any special condition for sandbox

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Most Welcome!!!

Answer (score 2):

First, rather than do a trigger, I would use a validation rule to perform the null checks or make the field required on the page layout depending on circumstances.

But if you must do it in trigger ( no idea why) make it easy on yourself and simplify trigger by putting the if no error condition code in the else instead of the if

```
trigger AccountCallout on Account (before update) {
// make the asynchronous web service callout   
  for (Account a : Trigger.new) {     
    if(a.Email__c == null ){
      a.Email__c.adderror('There was a problem updating the accounts. Email cannot be null');
    }else{
       //Some Operations
    }
  }
}
```

If that does not work for you then your email__c is not blank. Also note that you will need to bulkify `some operations` if you are making a call to your async method here note that if one record has an error the rest of the records being updated will be sent to the other method.